# delphi 7 function result can be undefined

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, undefined

I wrote this function wich compares string and return TRUE if it matches and FALSE if it doesn't.

The only problem is that when I compile, I get an error saying that the result can be undefined. I know this is not a problem as there are only 2 possible outcome in this particular situation but I'm kind of a perfectionnist and I want to get better. 
Can any of you enlighten me?

```
function filterUPC(upc: String): Boolean; 
var
  i, pos1: integer;
  Plano: TStringList;
  upcPlano: String;
begin
  Plano := TStringList.Create;
  if (fmMain.lblPlanook.Visible) and 
     not (fmMain.lblPlanook.Caption = 'INCOMPATIBLE') then
  begin
    Plano.LoadFromFile(fmMain.ebPlano.Text);
    for i := 0 to Plano.Count - 1 do
    begin
      pos1:=AnsiPos(';', Plano[i]);
      upcPlano := AnsiMidStr(Plano[i], pos1 + 1, 12);
      if (upc = upcPlano) then
      begin
        Result := TRUE;
        Break;
      end
      else if (i = Plano.Count - 1) then
      begin
        Result := FALSE;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := FALSE;
  end;
  Plano.Free;
end;
```

Comment: If you seriously want to get better, you could *please* start by learning to properly format your code. Being able to read it easily (and enabling others to do so) results in much better (and far more maintainable) code. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result is undefined if `Plano` is empty. In that case, the for-loop never executes and `Result` is never set.

Also, you should really wrap the TStringList create/free in a try/finally (since you're a perfectionist ;)

Here's what I would do:

```
function filterUPC(upc: String): Boolean;
var
  i, pos1: integer;
  Plano: TStringList;
  upcPlano: String;
begin
  Result := FALSE;
  Plano := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if (fmMain.lblPlanook.Visible) and (fmMain.lblPlanook.Caption <> 'INCOMPATIBLE') then
    begin
      Plano.LoadFromFile(fmMain.ebPlano.Text);
      for i := 0 to Plano.Count -1 do
      begin
        pos1 := AnsiPos(';', Plano[i]);
        upcPlano := AnsiMidStr(Plano[i], pos1 + 1, 12);
        if (upc = upcPlano) then
        begin
          Result := TRUE;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end
  finally
    Plano.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I've added `Result:=FALSE;` to the top, and removed the `else` checks. The try/finally guarantees that Plano will be freed, even if an exception is raised.

Comment: So I should just add "and if Plano.Count=0" to the else if i=Plano...? And can you explain quickly why I should wrap in try...finally? Thank you!

Comment: Edited. You can't add Plano.Count=0 to the else if, because it's inside the for-loop : if the for condition is never true, that code will never execute.

Comment: `try..finally` means that no matter what happens, the code in the `finally` is guaranteed to be executed. This means that, if you create something just before the `try` and free it in the `finally`, it's guaranteed to be freed; you can't accidentally forget or hit a code path that exits without the `finally` running. See [Writing a finally block](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Writing_a_Finally_Block_%28Delphi%29) for more info. (And +1 to @Blorgbeard, BTW.) :)